# How to hide/show date picker on button click?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a UIDatePicker and I want to hide and show on UIButton Click .

For this I am using BOOL variable isTouchFirst.but it hide and show on second event of button.

Please resolve this problem.And also check first it work on double click event.

```
if(isTouchFirst){   
        isTouchFirst=NO;
        self. DatePicker.hidden=NO; 
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        _DatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        formatedDate=[[NSString alloc]init];
        formatedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.DatePicker.date];
        self.SelectedDate.text =formatedDate;
        [DatePicker setMinimumDate: [NSDate date]];
        _goDateForcustmoeDetail=formatedDate;
    }
 else {  
       isTouchFirst=YES;
       self. DatePicker.hidden=YES;
      }
```

Comment: make sure in viewDidLoad or ViewWilAppear give value isTouchFirst=YES;

Comment: What is the initial value of TouchFirst.?

Comment: All works fine for me. Xcode 7.1.

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL datePickerHidden;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    datePickerHidden = YES;

    // _datePicker = [UIDatePicker alloc...
    [_datePicker setHidden: datePickerHidden];

    // UIButton *dateHiddenSwitchBtn = [UIButton alloc...
    dateHiddenSwitchBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(switchDatePickerHidden) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:dateHiddenSwitchBtn];
}

- (void)switchDatePickerHidden
{
    if (datePickerHidden) datePickerHidden = NO;
    else datePickerHidden = YES;

    [_datePicker setHidden: datePickerHidden];
}
```

Comment: Then you're definitely doing something wrong, but with that sloppy attitude you can figure it out yourself then! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make it `hidden = YES` by default

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
   sender.selected = !sender.selected;
   datePicker.hidden = !sender.selected;
}
```